# Aforge Unity3D Integration IPCam Image Stutter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aforge, ip-camera

I have a question about Aforge for IPCam (remote).

First off, I already can integrate it with unity (2019.1.7), the problem is the image stream is stuttering like what you can see from the video attachment.

[video stutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNI2j.gif)

Here's the script I'm using to get the stream

```
private void OnEnable()
 {
     transform.eulerAngles = initRot;
     if (mjpegStream != null)
         mjpegStream.Start();
 }
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     camTexture = new Texture2D(2 , 2);
     // create MJPEG video source
     mjpegStream = new MJPEGStream(camIPAddress);

     // set event handlers
     mjpegStream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(StreamImage);
     // start the video source
     mjpegStream.Start();
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     if (dataGet)
     {
         camTexture.LoadImage(jpegstream.ToArray());
             if(screenDisplay.texture != camTexture)
                 screenDisplay.texture = camTexture;
             counter = 0;
             dataGet = false;
     }
 }
 void StreamImage(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
 {
     jpegstream = eventArgs.Frame;
     dataGet = true;
 }
```

The question is, does anyone know how to make the image to not stutter?

Is it a problem from the stream I'm getting or from ToArray() function of MemoryStream or maybe other problem that I'm not aware of?
Please note that this happen with different ipcam I got from online too